# Using parse_ini_file() skip part of file - PHP

Tags: php, parsing, ini

I am parsing .ini file which looks like:

```
06ARname7=DVOJKABIN ULTIMATE [19]
06ARcode8=25
06ARname8=DVOJKABINA ADVANTA [25]
06ARcode9=24
06ARname9=DVOJKABINA CANYON [24]
06AUcode0=
06AUname0=
06AUcode1=01
06AUname1=ZÁKLADNÍ MODEL [01]
06AUcode2=50
06AUname2=50'S [50]
06AUcode3=51
06AUname3=60'S [51]
06AUcode4=52
06AUname4=70'S [52]
06AUcode5=31
06AUname5=CUP [31]
```

It have around 35k lines, somehow parse_ini_file() make first 11k and from on line to another it skip around 24k and do last 1k.
Place where it skip file:

```
06AUname3=60'S [51]
06AUcode4=52
06AUname4=70'S [52] // this is last one it do before SKIP
06AUcode5=31
06AUname5=CUP [31]
06AUcode6=02
06AUname6=DESIGN [02]
.
.
.
9305name4=RSV MILLE BOL D'OR [06]
9305code5=02 // again start working here
9305name5=RSV MILLE R [02]
9305code6=04
```

My code for parsing is really simple:

```
$ini = parse_ini_file($path);
foreach($ini as $code => $name)
{   
    // parse things like AMBITION [13] to 2 strings             
    $data = explode("[" , rtrim($name, "]"));
    var_dump($code);
    echo "<br>";
    echo $i++;
    echo "<br>-----------------<br>";                   
}
```

Can someone advise me where can be a problem?
Is there any limits for this function? How ever I try it always parse only 5078 lines (even if I edit file and delete some lines )

Comment: quotes `'` can be an issue.

Comment: Hi @Jigar can you please be more specific? I dont see any quotes there and if missing quotes is problem it will miss in first 10k rows as well, or not?